# convert big endian to mid little endian

Tags: c, bitwise-operators, bit, bit-shift

I have the following big endian in C:

```
int32_t num = 0x01234567;
```

I'd like to convert it to mid little endian like this : `0x45670123`

How do I use the bitwise operator to do that in C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple approach would be:

- Read a byte from `num` with the AND operator.
- Shift the read byte to the position you want in the output number.
- OR the shifted byte with your output number.
- Repeat until done.

Example:

```
uint32_t num = 0x01234567;
uint32_t output = 0;

uint32_t firstByte = num & 0xff000000; // firstByte is now 0x01000000
// Where do we want to have 0x01 in the output number?
// 0x45670123
//       ^^ here
// Where is 0x01 currently?
// 0x01000000
//   ^^ here
// So to go from 0x01000000 to 0x00000100 we need to right shift the byte by 16 (4 positions * 4 bits)
uint32_t adjByte = firstByte >> 16; // adjByte is now 0x0100
// OR with output
output |= adjByte;
```

[AND, Shift & OR operator on wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C)

Comment: printf("%x\n", output);  // output is 100, not 0x45670123

Comment: Yes you need to repeat these steps for the other 3 bytes.